# Plone z3c.form.GroupForm with inline validation

Tags: validation, plone, z3c.form

I'm stuck using two schemas to build a z3c.GroupForm that has inline validation:

Following https://pypi.python.org/pypi/z3c.form#group-forms I did:

```
from plone.directives.dexterity import AddForm
from z3c.form import field
from z3c.form import group, form

class CustomerGroup( group.Group ):
    label = u'Customer'
    fields = field.Fields(ICustomer, prefix='customer')

class CustomerRegistrationAddForm(group.GroupForm, AddForm):
    ignoreContext = True
    fields = field.Fields(IEmailUser).omit('customer')
    groups = (CustomerGroup,)
```

This works. But it gives me really plain rendering and no inline validation.
I tried to include mixings from plone.autoform but these seem not to be compatible -> MRO errors.

I am quite sure that I missed something. There are plone.app.z3cform and other wrappers for z3c.form usage in Plone. But I do not find an example of using them for z3c.groups, so I tried the basic z3c variant.

The usecase I like to achieve is the following: A form that has the fields of Schema A and Schema B each in a tab, respectively. The form action handling then is manually coded and will take care of the handling of underlying content types. With other words: no dexterity "positive connotation" magic will/should be used.

**But I like to have inline validation according to the schema hints and adapters I registered for the schemas.**

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved. The groups of Z3c are called fieldsets in Plone, now.
The following does the trick.

```
from plone.autoform.form import AutoExtensibleForm
from plone.supermodel import model
from z3c.form import form
from plone.autoform import directives

class ICustomerRegistration( IEmailUser, ICustomer ):
    model.fieldset('EmailUser',
        label=_(u"EMail User"),
        fields=['email', 'firstname', 'lastname', ]
        )

    model.fieldset('Customer',
        label=_(u"Customer"),
        fields=['enterprise',
                'street',
                'house_number',
                'postal_code',
                'city',
                ]
        )

class CustomerRegistrationAddForm(AutoExtensibleForm, form.Form):
    ignoreContext = True
    schema = ICustomerRegistration
```